# emacsでMacOSXのショートカットキーをバインドする方法

Tags: macos, emacs

MacOSXでは`command+control+f`のショートカットキーでウインドウのフルスクリーン切り替えを行うことができますが、emacsではキーの優先度が奪われてしまうためか、フルスクリーン切り替えを行うことができません

```
(kbd "<C-s-268632070>")
```

上記のコードでcommand+control+fのキーを判定することができるところまではわかったのですが、emacsからMacOSXのキーボードショートカットを実行する方法としてどういったものが考えられるでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こんなんでいかがでしょう
`(global-set-key (kbd "<C-s-268632070>") 'toggle-frame-fullscreen)`

ここを参照しました。
http://emacswiki.org/emacs/FullScreen#toc26

Comment: 無事動作しました。ありがとうございましたm(_ _)m